# Why so many programmers say unicode is bad?

Tags: unicode

Everday is see people in forums or on twitter posting that unicode is bad.

Today I've read someone writing:

> There are only 1,112,064 hard problems in computer science and all of them are Unicode.

Can you guys explain me, what's the problem with it?

I thought it isn't bad because of its huge collection of characters.

Comment: I think this is a wrong forum. Try perhaps StackOverflow or Programmers.stackexchange.

Comment: I suggest you don't ask on StackOverflow, that's for programming questions! This is just asking for an explanation where as just performing a Google search will bring up the answers! There is also no need to swear, even if you do * it out!

Comment: IF only it was just a "huge collection of characters". In reality it's a huge collection of characters plus a huge collection of rules to pander to countries with writing systems that don't fit the mould of "a sequence of characters arranged left to right".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, they're stating their opinion. It doesn't mean that unicode is bad, it just means that those programmers, when they used it, faced problems and they formed their opinions based on that.

Take a look at the following articles, they explain the basics of unicode. Hopefully, they can help you understand the opinions stated on twitter or forums.

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

[What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)